# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(\frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n})^{n-k}$ Stiriling formula

Tags: probability-theory, factorial, poisson-distribution

> I am supposed to study the behaviour of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}(\frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n})^{n-k}$ making use of Stirling formula: $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi}n^n\sqrt{n}e^{-n}$.

After replacing the $n!$ by the Stirling formula I got a complex expression I cannot simplify.

After commentary here is the expression: $\frac{n^n\sqrt{n}e^{-n}}{(n-k)^{n-k}\sqrt{n-k}e^{-n+k}}(\frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n})^{n-k}$

**Question**:

**1)** How should I proceed to compute the above limit using the formula for $n!$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts, especially your "complex expression".

Comment: @GNUSupporter I guess you are the downvoter. Anyway the expression is there. I do not think it was to much of an effort to understand what was the expression. But it looks like it was so there it is! Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @GNUSupporter So please tell me what you think of the expression instead of copying  pasting the posts of the Math.SE.

Comment: I'm making my previous comment since it was a PSQ.  [Not even diamond mod](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2712921/timeline) can be immune from CRUDE's deletion of PSQ.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean by PSQ.

Comment: Some of the terms can be crossed out, like $n^n$ and $e^n$.  [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/psq-and-the-faq) means "Problem Statement Question".

Comment: @GNUSupporter I do not see how since the denominator has $n-k$. What are you thinking?

Comment: @GNUSupporter It is not $e^n$ but $e^{-{n}}$

Comment: I crossed out $e^{-n}$. That is right. But what are you thinking regarding $n^n$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77696/discussion-between-gnu-supporter-and-pedro-gomes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \frac{n^n\sqrt{n}e^{-n}}{(n-k)^{n-k}\sqrt{n-k} \, e^{-n+k} \, k!} \left( \frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n} \right)^k \left( 1-\frac{\lambda t_{\alpha}}{n} \right)^{n-k} \\
&= \frac{(\lambda t_\alpha)^k}{k! \, e^k} \, \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-k}} \, \frac{(n-\lambda t_\alpha)^{n-k}}{(n-k)^{n-k}} \\
&= \frac{(\lambda t_\alpha)^k}{k! \, e^k} \, \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-k}} \, \left( \frac{n-\lambda t_\alpha}{n-k}\right)^{-k}}_{\to 1 \text{ as } n \to \infty} \, \left( \frac{n-\lambda t_\alpha}{n-k}\right)^{n} \\
&= \frac{(\lambda t_\alpha)^k}{k! \, e^k} \, \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n-k}} \, \left( \frac{n-\lambda t_\alpha}{n-k}\right)^{-k}}_{\to 1 \text{ as } n \to \infty} \, \left( 1+\frac{1}{(n-k)/(k-\lambda t_\alpha)}\right)^{n} \\
&\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} \frac{(\lambda t_\alpha)^k}{k! \, e^k} \, e^{k-\lambda t_\alpha} \\
&= \frac{(\lambda t_\alpha)^k}{k! \, e^{\lambda t_\alpha}}
\end{align}

Remarks: This can be done *without* using Stirling's Formula.  You may refer to another related question *[Limit of a probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2702120/290189)* for details.